Manim installation stuck
After installation of chocolatey and python 311. It is written on windows PowerShell
"Restricting write permission to Administrator"
and it get stuck. What should I do?
I don't know what to enter in PowerShell to continue the process.
Please help

Update: It takes about almost one hour. After that process started.
